# What is the generating function to the number of ways of expressing n dollars as a 1,2 and 5 dollar coins.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I need to solve this problem using generating functions:

> What is the generating function to the number of ways of expressing n dollars as a 1,2 and 5 dollar coins.

I wasn't able to solve the $\ (1+x^2+x^4)^n\ $ part.

Comment: Is this the full and exact problem statement? It's not very clear to me

Comment: Yes, this is the question

Comment: Maybe you mean number of ways of expressing $n$ dollars as a collection of $1$, $2$ and $5$ dollar coins?

Comment: Yes, It looked clear enough for me. I will edit it,

Answer (score 0):

We're looking for
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n $$
where $a_n$ is the number of ways of expressing $n$ dollars as a collection of $1, 2, 5$ dollar coins.
$$a_n = \sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3 = n} m_{k_1, 1}m_{k_2, 2}m_{k_3, 5} $$
where $m_{k_1, 1}$ is the number of ways to express $k_1$ dollars in terms of $1$ dollar coins, $m_{k_2, 2}$ is the number of ways of expressing $k_2$ dollars in terms of $2$ dollar coins, and $m_{k_3, 5}$ is the number of ways of expressing $k_3$ dollars in terms of $5$ dollar coins. From this:
$$F(x) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_{n, 1}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_{n, 2}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_{n, 5}x^n\right) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{5n}\right)=\\ = \frac{1}{1-x}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x^5} $$
If the order of the coins is important, then we can derive a recurrence:
$$b_{n+5} = b_{n+4}+b_{n+3}+b_n,\ n\geq 0 \\ b_0 = 0,\ b_1 = 1,\ b_2 = 2, \ b_3 = 3, \ b_4 = 5$$
It's because there is $3$ possible cases, we have $1, 2$ or $5$ dollar coin at the end, and we take as much dollars from the whole if that's the case. Then we have
$$G(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n = x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+5}x^{n+5} = \\ = p(x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (b_{n+4}+b_{n+3}+b_n)x^{n+5} = p(x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^{n+5} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+3}x^{n+5} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+4}x^{n+5} $$
where $p(x) = x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4$. Then we can simplify the $3$ sums
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^{n+5} = x^5\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n = x^5G(x) $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+3}x^{n+5} = x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+3}x^{n+3} = x^2\sum_{n=3}^\infty b_nx^n = x^2(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^2 b_nx^n)= \\ = x^2(G(x)-2x^2-x) =  x^2G(x) - 2x^4-x^3 $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+4}x^{n+5} = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n+4}x^{n+4} = x\sum_{n=4}^\infty b_nx^n = x(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n - \sum_{n=0}^3 b_nx^n) = \\ = x(G(x)-3x^3-2x^2-x) = xG(x)-3x^4-2x^3-x^2 $$
So we can now calulate what $G(x)$ is
$$G(x) = p(x)+(x^5+x^2+x)G(x)-5x^4-3x^3-x^2 = (x^5+x^2+x)G(x)+x+x^2 $$
$$G(x) = \frac{x+x^2}{1-(x+x^2+x^5)} $$

Comment: Follow up question - What if I the order of the coins is important. How will it change?

Comment: @Igor I've edited my answer

Comment: I didn't quiet understand the transition. Why is G(X) defined this way and what is 
x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4? I lost you there..

Comment: @Igor If $b_n$ is number of ways of expressing $n$ dollars as a collection of $1, 2, 5$ dollar coins, so that the order of coins matters, then from definition, it's generating function is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$. This is just the definition. $x+2x^2+3x^3+5x^4 = \sum_{n=0}^4 b_nx^n$, we split the sum in two parts.

Comment: Why can't you say this is the answer? $$ \frac{1}{(1-x^2-x^3-x^5)} $$ I am just summing all the possibilities for choosing coins.

Comment: Because it's false. Didn't you read what I wrote?

Comment: I have, but we didn't learn recurrence yet in our course so I am trying to see it from my point of view..

Answer (score 0):

The generating function for coins of value $k$ is
$\dfrac1{1-x^k}$.

For different value coins, multiply their generating functions.